# AttributeError at /admin/fluent_comments/fluentcomment/

Tags: python, django, django-fluent

Try to implement django_fluent_comments. It works perfectly with another clsses, but with News I have the following error (though the classes are mostly similar):

```
AttributeError at /admin/fluent_comments/fluentcomment/

'News' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'
```

The Traceback links me to the comments template:

```
Error during template rendering

In template /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 91
'News' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'
```

I don't want to add a get_absolute_url method to the "news" class because I don't understand why in other cases it works without it.

Comment: I haven't used django_fluent_comments, but if you [search the repository](https://github.com/django-fluent/django-fluent-comments/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=get_absolute_url) for `get_absolute_url`, the app uses that method in the views and templates. There do not seem to be fallbacks if the method doesn't exist, so it doesn't look like you can avoid creating the method.